# How to find the environment variable for a file?

Tags: environment-variables, glibc

I am using the custom package manager [spack](https://spack.readthedocs.io/) to manage the packages on my system, including gcc.
I have created the exact same spack installation setup on two computers and want to run a software that depends on the packages installed with this. Both of them require `GLIBCXX_3.4.29` to be installed. On computer 1, the software runs fine, on computer 2, I get a `GLIBCXX_3.4.29 not found` error. I would like to see where computer 1 is fetching the `GLIBCXX_3.4.29` file from to fix the error on computer 2. Is there a way to find out which environment variable path a particular binary or file is located in?

`apt policy libstdc++6` has the same output on both computers

`strings /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.29` returns `'/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6': No such file` on both computers.

Comment: `strings /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.29` ? And your problem is likely a missing symlink.

Comment: @steeldriver have edited my question accordingly

Comment: I've deleted my previous comments - there was no mention of the `spack` package manager in the original post; `apt` may be unhelpful in that case.

Comment: Since you are using a non-standard package manager, a good starting point might be to use `ldd /path/to/executable` to see exactly which version of `libstdc++` is being linked in each case.

Comment: did you try to activated your environment on computer 1? check your [Environment Docs](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/environments.html#activating-an-environment) and also check your `spack.yaml` to add LD_LIBRARY_PATH.